# Module parameter permission

Tags: module, kernel, kernel-module

I'm new to kernel programming. When I was going through `module_param`, I was confused by the permission value 0. It was explained that it won't get an entry in sysfs, while the others like `S_IRUGO` would get an entry. I couldn't understand the concept.

What does the perm value 0 indicate? 
When do we need a sysfs entry? What is the need for that?

Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can module parameters in some ways to a kernel module. Assuming a kernel module `foo` with a parameter named `bar`:

- Using the kernel command line which can be provided in your bootloader configuration. To see the command line for the current boot, run `cat /proc/cmdline`. Example output: `BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 foo.bar=some-value`
- While loading a kernel module using `insmod` or `modprobe`: `modprobe foo bar=some-value`.
- When a module is loaded, you can usually see find the parameter `bar` for module `foo` at `/sys/module/foo/parameters/bar`.

A permission value of `0` prevents the sysfs entry from being created (third bullet above). An example usage in the kernel code is to allow for enabling debug without exposing this parameter in sysfs.

An example of a readable/writable module parameter is `acpi`. It allows you to dynamically set the debugging information that should be generated. Available as `acpi.debug_level` for the kernel command line or as the `/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level` sysfs entry.